# Websphere and MQ as JMS provider: Lost messages

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, websphere-8, mq

We are using the following

**Websphere 8.0.0.10**

**MQ as JMS Provider**

I have an MDB that is putting messages on to another Queue like this (gets triggered by a another message)

```
    if (connectionFactory == null) {
        throw new BatchProcessException("connectionFactory injection failed");
    }
    if (queue == null) {
        throw new BatchProcessException("queue injection failed");
    }

    List<Customer> customers = getAllCustomers();

    if (customers != null && customers.size() > 0) {

        try {
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            connection.start();

            for (Customer customer : customers) {


                Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
                producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
                TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(customer.toString());
                producer.send(textMessage);
                session.close();
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            LOG.error("error", e);
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                    connection = null;
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    LOG.error("error closing mq connection", e);
                }
            }
        }
```

As you can see, this code is running in a loop creating and putting messages.
All this works fine for us in a lower environment but in another environment, we hit a limit of 10000 msgs only allowed to be put this way. Dont know where the other messages disappeared. We have checked max queue depth and MAXUMSGS. The transaction logs for the queue manager are also the same size. Unfortunately this code running inside an MDB does not get any exception. Could someone please shed some light. Any prompt response would be greatly appreciated. Any details sought would be provided immediately.

I am not an MQ expert but we have configured Websphere to put messages Asynchronously. What that means in terms of a NON_PERSISTENT messages and NOT_TRANSACTED session, if someone could explain would also be very useful.

Comment: The transacted flag on a session gets ignored when in a Java EE container, so whether it is transacted or not depends on whether the MDB is configured for a transaction or not.

Comment: @Alasdair, The MDB is actually running with a a transaction attribute of NotSupported (default for Container Managed  MDB)

Comment: @T.Rob, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you collect a JMS trace on the WebSphere Application Server *=info:JMSApi=all:Messaging=all:com.ibm.mq.*=all:WAS.j2c=all:Transaction=all from https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21153217  and https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21199176 and see if the trace gives any indication of failure. That would be where I would start.

Comment: Also, note non-persistent level of service here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/cjj9000_.html (that is from version 7 but should be no different with any version of the application server)

Comment: @AlexandrePolozoff, unfortunately this issue seems to be happening in a PRODUCTION environment only. We have not been able to replicate it in non prod environments. Switching the trace on in production is not something we can easily suggest. Any other ideas? I wish we could have replicated it else where and gathered the trace

Comment: If this is happening in production then I would recommend opening a PMR with IBM Support and setting the ticket to Sev 1 so we can get the appropriate SMEs engaged.